# How does the wind-up box work in FNAF 2?

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys-2

The wind-up music box in Five Nights at Freddy's 2 doesn't seem to work for me. I click and hold the box for a really long time but nothing happens. It just continues to unwind.

Comment: When you say the box, do you mean the button you are suppose to click and hold or are you actually trying to click and hold the music box itself?  There is a button just to the left of the camera map that you are suppose to actually click and hold.

Answer (score 1):

When the Music Box fully unwinds the Puppet Master pops out and kills you. You have to keep it wound up so the Puppet Master doesn't kill you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are **holding and pressing the button next to the box**. If that doesn't work, You probably have a problem with your device.

Answer (score 0):

The "Music Box," is supposed to be used to keep mangle and Marinet (The Puppet) at bay. **It is meant to unwind, so make sure to take the time to check it and wind it back up.** Once it start getting dangerously low you should get an yellow caution symbol on your monitor. If it gets critically low then it will have a red caution symbol on your monitor which usually means it's so low that mangle and/or Marinet will attack you even if it does get wound back up. If it gets completely low its usually too late and they head to your office.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have to click and hold the "wind up music box" button and make sure that the white pie beside the button is always filled, as it indicates the amount of winding in the music box.  If the pie becomes empty, the music box will open and the marionette will come and get you, as there is no way to resist it because it can see through the Freddy mask and the flashlight doesn't work on her (Yes "her" because of Charlie).